# Return values of POSIX functions

Tags: c, posix, return-value, standards-compliance

I try to write POSIX compatible code that is shared between two POSIX compliant operating systems, namely QNX and a Linux variant.

I just found that there are small differences regarding the specification of function return values e.g. of `pthread_mutex_trylock()`. One documentation says it returns `EOK` (which evaluates to `0`) the other says it returns plain `0` in case of success.

I assume I can safely check return values `== 0` or `!= 0` and avoid the QNX `EOK` macro.

My questions:

1. Does POSIX explicitely define which values have to be returned by functions in case of success and/or error?
2. Strictly spoken, is a function that is specified to return `EOK` (not `0`) POSIX compliant?
3. Is `EOK` part of some standard?

Comment: This question is pure academical. First of all, Posix is about source-code compatibility, not about binary compatibility. `EOK` is not specified by posix and the mentioned function is required to return `0` on success, so you are safe to use the constant 0 here. I am not aware of a standard containing `EOK`.

Comment: @Ctx: Well, source compatibility is exactly the issue here. EOK seems to break that compatibility (unnecessarily). Anyway since your comment answered my questions, why don't you make it an actual answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There are POSIX manual pages, consult them to find out what the POSIX definition of a function is. For example: http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3posix/pthread_mutex_trylock/. In general, POSIX is very consistent, and in all cases where the return value is only used to signal success or failure, `0` means success.
2. If `EOK` equals `0`, then the QNX implementation is POSIX compliant. However, as you already said, use `0` in your own code to ensure it compiles on all platforms.
3. As far as I can tell, it's not part of a platform-independent standard. Either you avoid using it, or if you believe `EOK` is more clear, then you can write this in your program:

.

```
#ifndef EOK
#define EOK 0
#endif
```